# Dynamic url sharing through fb using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-sharer, window.location

How can I put dynamic url in fb share button.
My fb share button code is look like this-

```
<div id="fbshare_button" class="fb-share-button" data-href="window.location.href" data-type="button_count"></div>
```

and I am trying this code to change url:

```
$(".fb-share-button").data('href',window.location.href);
```

You can see here "https://31ragas.in/?member=avirbhavverma&title=Dil-Cheez&album=Coke-Studio" that window.location.href providing right url but changes are not reflecting in fb share.

Comment: where did you put or call the FB SDK? before you change the href or after that? and what did you change your url to, I don't see any difference in the HTML and jQuery ( the same window.location.href )